# Z Shell: Inputing Alias Content Produces Different Output Than Calling Alias Itself

Tags: printf, zsh, alias, xargs

I type this command:

```sh
$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/nl1.conf | grep PrivateKey | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs printf "\033[1;34m%s\033[0m\n"
PqyfQ3CtdcoCwgQjW8iGbypofi4TUyJSS5PmVa67sPCTS=
```

The output is bold, **as expected**.

When calling this alias (set in `.zshrc`):

```
alias mlprivkey="sudo cat /etc/wireguard/nl1.conf | grep PrivateKey | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs printf \"\033[1;34m%s\033[0m\n\""
```

… the first two lines of the following output is **not** expected:

```sh
$ mlprivkey
PrivateKey
=
PqyfQ3CtdcoCwgQjW8iGbypofi4TUyJSS5PmVa67sPCTS=
```

I thought the alias would output same result as typing the command set itself.

Comment: Youi need to escape `$3` because it's in the global double quotes. Try `\$3`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. Your suggestion did help.